# NSButton event handling in C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

I'm creating a thin layer of C++ on top of Cocoa widgets and there's a problem of handling NSButton events without ObjC object as a target.

Any ideas how could I use c++ class methods to handle button click?

For example:

```
[button setTarget:cppObj];
[button setAction:@(cppObjMethod:)]
```

The code above doesn't work, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set the target and action to an Objective-c class / method which itself calls the C++ code.

Comment: Yeah, seems like I'll have to go that way - subclass every wrapped widget and implement event methods that work with my logic. wxWidgets does it differently, looks like it involves some ASM magic, but I don't need that now.

Comment: Yeah, you *could* use the runtime methods and interecept messages / pass them through to c++ code etc but it could get very dirty, very quickly!